# Date Concatenation in the script

Tags: qliksense

I have a Calendar extension retrieve the date format like (DD-MM-YY) and I need to add to this variable the time but it is a fixed time for the begin and the end. The script below failed to execute.

```
where "begin" >= ('$(vFromDate)' || ' 00:00:00') and "end" <= ('$(vToDate)' || ' 23:59:59').
```

I tried the (+) it is also failed instead of (||).

Please note that I am connected with a PostgresSQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are best to use the date# format when generating dates

```
where "begin" >= (date#($(vFromDate)&' 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS')) and "end" <= (date#($(vToDate)&' 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS'))
```

Comment: not a problem, I think the end date might need amending to 23:59:59 before you implement it

Comment: yep, I have realized that.  It is obvious that a typo mistake  :).

Comment: Also "&" is used in a Qlik Expression not in a SQL script.

Comment: Also I have found another way. I used another variable adding the time (00:00:00) in the variable definition. Then, using this variable in the SQL script which contain the full date format that I want (i.e 2016-13-04 00:00:00).